# features label didn't appear for some featuresClass

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-engine, labeling

i'm working in a stand-alone application using arcEngine , arcSDE geodatabase , VB.net 
so my problem is  that i can't appear the features label for some featuresClass.
when i opened it in arcMap to test it, despite Labels are set in Properties, layers are checked to label in the TOC,I'm unable to get labels to display in Arcmap 10.

like this question but mine is different :
[Labels not appearing on any layer in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7980/arcmap-10-labels-not-appearing)

i'm not looking to change my mxd file. all feature classes are in a geodatabase.

Comment: when i convert this featureClass to shapefile features label displayed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it was a problem in some geometries so i execute this tools :

Repair Geometry (Data Management) and now the labels appear nicely

link : http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000